# Is it possible to select seconds in a p-calendar?

Tags: angular

[image: P-calendar with time-picker]

Is it possible to let the user enter seconds when selecting a date and time?

Comment: Is it primefaces calendar? If not, please add link to the library that you are using.

Comment: Yes, it is the primeng calendar :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to show seconds for p-calendar. Set the `showSeconds` property to `true` (the default value for showSeconds is false).
Have a look at the following link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/prime-ng-calendar-gpvzqm

Comment: what about showing milliseconds ?